# Ruby equivalent of Perl Data::Dumper

Tags: ruby, perl-module

I am learning Ruby & Perl has this very convenient module called Data::Dumper, which allows you to recursively analyze a data structure (like hash) & allow you to print it. This is very useful while debugging. Is there some thing similar for Ruby?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Look into pp

example:

```
  require 'pp'
  x = { :a => [1,2,3, {:foo => bar}]}
  pp x
```

there is also the inspect method which also works quite nicely

```
  x = { :a => [1,2,3, {:foo => bar}]}
  puts x.inspect
```

Answer (score 3):

I normally use a YAML dump if I need to quickly check something.

In `irb` the syntax is simply `y obj_to_inspect`. In a normal Ruby app, you may need to add a `require 'YAML'` to the file, not sure.

Here is an example in `irb`:

```
>> my_hash = {:array => [0,2,5,6], :sub_hash => {:a => 1, :b => 2}, :visible => true}
=> {:sub_hash=>{:b=>2, :a=>1}, :visible=>true, :array=>[0, 2, 5, 6]}
>> y my_hash  # <----- THE IMPORTANT LINE
--- 
:sub_hash: 
  :b: 2
  :a: 1
:visible: true
:array: 
- 0
- 2
- 5
- 6
=> nil
>>
```

The final `=> nil` just means the method didn't return anything. It has nothing to do with your data structure.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [Marshal](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Marshal.html),  [amarshal](http://www.a-k-r.org/amarshal/), [YAML](http://www.yaml.org)