# Ruby equivalent of perl's "Data::Dumper" for printing deep nested hashes/arrays

Tags: ruby, perl

This is not a duplicate of [Ruby equivalent of Perl Data::Dumper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159426/ruby-equivalent-of-perl-datadumper). That question is more than 3.5 years old and hence want to check are there any new options available in Ruby since then.

I am looking for perl's `Dumper` equivalent in ruby. I don't care what Dumper does behind the curtains. I have used it extensively for printing deep nested hashes and array in perl. So far I haven't found an alternative in ruby (Or I may not have find a way to make good use of available alternatives in Ruby).

This is my perl code and its Output:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $hash;

$hash->{what}->{where} = "me";
$hash->{what}->{who} = "you";
$hash->{which}->{whom} = "she";
$hash->{which}->{why} = "him";

print Dumper($hash);
```

OUTPUT:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'what' => {
                      'who' => 'you',
                      'where' => 'me'
                    },
          'which' => {
                       'why' => 'him',
                       'whom' => 'she'
                     }
        };
```

Just Love the  Dumper. :)

In ruby, I tried `pp`, `p`, `inspect` and `yaml`. here is my same code in ruby and its output:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require "pp"
require "yaml"
hash = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }

hash[:what][:where] = "me"
hash[:what][:who] = "you"
hash[:which][:whom] = "she"
hash[:which][:why] = "him"

pp(hash)
puts "Double p did not help. Lets try single p"
p(hash)
puts "Single p did not help either...lets do an inspect"
puts hash.inspect
puts "inspect was no better...what about yaml...check it out"
y hash
puts "yaml is good for this test code but not for really deep nested structures"
```

OUTPUT:

```
{:what=>{:where=>"me", :who=>"you"}, :which=>{:whom=>"she", :why=>"him"}}
Double p did not help. Lets try single p
{:what=>{:where=>"me", :who=>"you"}, :which=>{:whom=>"she", :why=>"him"}}
Single p did not help either...lets do an inspect
{:what=>{:where=>"me", :who=>"you"}, :which=>{:whom=>"she", :why=>"him"}}
inspect was no better...what about yaml...check it out
--- 
:what: 
  :where: me
  :who: you
:which: 
  :whom: she
  :why: him
yaml is good for this test code but not for really deep nested structures
```

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by *yaml is good for this test code but not for really deep nested structures* ?

Comment: yaml output is painful (atleast for me) to read and interpret as compared to Dumper when it comes to deep hashes/arrays.

Comment: downvotes? what for? what's wrong with the question?

Comment: how about converting to JSON? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1823885/223226

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: @sawa - the question is, what is a Ruby module that does what Data::Dumper does in Perl?   Seems pretty clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby equivalent of Perl Data::Dumper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159426/ruby-equivalent-of-perl-datadumper)

Comment: One interesting comparison point would be how they work on cyclical data structures; a la `perl -MData::Dumper -e'$x = []; push @$x, $x; print Dumper($x)'`. JSON output doesn't support such things.

Comment: Another thing not possible in JSON is serialization of objects. Data::Dumper and YAML can deal with blessed objects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about [Awesome Print](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print):

```
require 'awesome_print'
hash = {what: {where: "me", who: "you"}, which: { whom: "she", why: "him"}}
ap hash
```

Output (actually with syntax highlighting):

```
{
     :what => {
        :where => "me",
          :who => "you"
    },
    :which => {
        :whom => "she",
         :why => "him"
    }
}
```

Comment: Aah, awesome_print is truly awesome. Thanks @Stefan