# Is a dump method in ruby similar to perl's Data::Dumper->Dump(object) method?

Tags: ruby

ruby newbie here.

The [Data::Dumper->Dump(object)](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) method in perl is awesome. It logs the entire structure of any object into stdout. Makes it really easy to debug. Basically looking for a method which can print the structure of any object irrespective of its type.

Is there a similar library/method in ruby?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2159426/2864740 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/18292538/2864740

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby equivalent of Perl Data::Dumper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159426/ruby-equivalent-of-perl-datadumper)

Answer (score 2):

Ruby has two such methods for debugging: `p` and `pp`.

The `p(x)` method is equivalent to:

```
puts x.inspect
```

The `pp` method is similar but *pretty*. That is it gives a more human-readable output.